mac M3_VS studio_CSS/HTML_Issue with live server extension
I have a Mac M3. VS Code is installed on it with the live server extension.
There are a couple of websites that were developed on another computer running Linux, and I cloned them onto my Mac.
When I try to launch them in the brave browser, it constantly tries to connect through a port, but without success. As a result, the site doesn’t load.
Could you help me figure out what I’m doing wrong?

Thank you very much
i tried to reinstall the application but no success

What does a connection problem have to do with HTML or CSS?

You may want to try changing the port.
Go to VSCode, and in the search bar type "Preferences" and click on User Settings. Then in the search type "Live Server Port" and change the number to 3000, 8000, 8080 or some other port.
Screenshot
Let me know if this doesn't help.

The issue is resolved. Previously, I was opening the folder with all the projects, and the port wasn’t working (although there were no issues on Linux). On Mac, I simply opened the specific project, and everything worked fine.
Thank you very much!
